# Sinatra optional parameter operator and syntax. What is the right syntax?

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

```
get '/foo/?bar'
  "Hi"
end
```

Will the urls:

```
www.yahoo.com/foo/about/blog   
www.theatlantic.com/foo/about
```

hit that route? Does the `?` operator work here? Or do I need two `?` marks? I am reading *Sinatra Up and Running* and it does not appear to have this listed. It seems important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right syntax is:

```
get '/foo/?:bar?' do
  "Hi"
end
```

Where first question mark makes preceding `/` optional and second makes preceding symbol `:bar` optional, so that:
`/foo/about` - yes
`/foo/about/blog` - no
`/foo` - yes
`/foo/` - yes

Otherwise you can make only `:bar` symbol optional with

```
get '/foo/:bar?' do
  "Hi"
end
```

so that:
`/foo/about` - yes
`/foo/about/blog` - no
`/foo` - no
`/foo/` - yes

To give you one more example, this option:

```
get '/go/?:bar' do 
    "wow"
end
```

is practically equivalent to this:

```
get '/go/:bar' do 
    "wow"
end
```

Comment: @Jwan622, you don't. Updated my answer.

Comment: It seems like /foo/about/blog should be yes?

Comment: @Jwan622, nope, it should be no. In fact, even `/foo/about/` is no in both cases (to make it yes you should use `/foo/:bar?/?`). To make `/foo/about/blog` yes, you can use, eg, `foo/:bar?/?/:hm?`. By the way, `:` is not necessary if you don't intend to use it from params hash afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an ordinary regular expressions to match routes. For instance, a very permissible "foo" route that accepts every route that has the <del>word</del> **sub-string** "foo":

```
get /foo/ do
  'From ANY path that includes the word foo!'
end
```

This will match:

1. `/foo`
2. `/foobar`
3. `/bar/another_foo/something_else`

Comment: Careful with the pattern: That regex doesn't match words, it matches sub-strings. It'd match "foo bar" and "foodie" equally. Use `/\bfoo\b/` to match words.

Comment: Yes, thats why I provided those examples.

Comment: Yes, you provided examples, but it's misleading to say it found a word. It found a sub-string. There's a difference between the two.

Comment: OK, but here's what I'd recommend. Don't use the `<del>` tag to mark a word deleted or use bold formatting on the replacement. We can tell what was added when by looking at the revision history, so just change the text. Also, I'd recommend rewording your code's message. I *can* do it, but I won't because it's bad form to change people's code, especially in answers.

Comment: Okay, thanks!! I will take care from next time and pay attention to the etiquette. Just to note: Your answers have helped me a lot and have inspired me to look at SO more frequently.